# MVC 4 - cannot create database using NuGet Package manager console

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget, database-migration, localdb

I'm trying to create a new database using Visual Studio 2012 NuGet package manager console.
I have done all the steps to enable migration, the Migrations folder was successfully created, and its configuration class was defined as the next:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyMVC4Project.Infrastructure.CategoryDb>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyMVC4Project.Infrastructure.CategoryDb context)
    {
        context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(d => d.Name,
            new Department() {Name = "dishes"},
            new Department() {Name = "Appliances"},
            new Department() {Name = "furniture"}
            );
    }
}
```

PM> update-database -Verbose

At which point I see the error message:

```
Using StartUp project 'MyMVC4Project'.
Using NuGet project ' MyMVC4Project '.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'MyMVC4Project.Infrastructure.CategoryDb' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
No pending code-based migrations.
Running Seed method.
```

Then no database is created in the App_data folder, I am expecting to find a localDb database not an SQL Express one, then the installed SQL Express instance have a different name than "SQLExpress", and in my web.config the default connection string points to a localDB instance.

Please, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons that I don't know it either you can't see the database from sqlServer, however, the database has not been created since you didn't hit your database implicitly. you need to do DB.SaveChanger(); or hit the database in your code in any other way.